# jQuery Address not working on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, browser-history

I'm using Asual's jQuery Address plugin to deeplink between content without the use of hashes (using the HTML5 History API).

Here is my code:

```
$.address.state("/").init(function(e){
    $('#nav li a').address(); // initializes
    if (e.value == "/") {
        $.address.value("/home"); // loads /home by default
    };
});

$.address.change(function(e) {
    // loads whatever page is in that /pages folder and puts the content in div#container
    $.get("/pages" + e.value + ".html", function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $('#container').html(""); //clears out the old content
        $('#container').html(data); //loads the new page in there
    });
});
```

This works perfectly when clicking the top navigation buttons. Even the back and forward buttons in the browser work like a charm. The issue is when refreshing/opening the url in another tab.
for example if I write http://domain.com it gets me to http://domain.com/home and the content is shown. If I refresh I get a 404 Error. The browser is looking for an actual /home file which of course doesn't exist (home.html instead).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

DD

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and got the same problem, ended using hashes.